# PHP + Javascript ошибка Unexpected token <

Tags: json, php, javascript

При передаче JSON на сервер получаю ошибку "Unexpected token <", подозреваю что неправильно вставил js код в php, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

Серверный код:

```
<?php
$route = $_POST['route'];
$timeInMinutes = $_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$timeInSeconds = $_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$averageSpeed = $_POST['averageSpeed'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];

$trackCoords1 = json_decode($route, false);
$final_time_m1 = json_decode($timeInMinutes, false);
$final_time_s_rounded1 = json_decode($timeInSeconds, false);
$aver_speed_km_h_rounded1 = json_decode($averageSpeed, false);
$total_km_rounded1 = json_decode($distance, false);
?>

<script>
var total_km_rounded = '<?php echo $total_km_rounded1; ?>';
document.write('Растояние: </br>' + total_km_rounded);
var final_time_m = '<?php echo $final_time_m1; ?>';
document.write('Время в минутах: </br>' + final_time_m);
var final_time_s_rounded = '<?php echo $final_time_s_rounded1; ?>';
document.write('Время в секундах: </br>' + final_time_s_rounded);
var aver_speed_km_h_rounded = '<?php echo $aver_speed_km_h_rounded1; ?>';
document.write('Средняя скорость: </br>' + aver_speed_km_h_rounded);
</script>
```

Клиентский код передачи JSON:

```
    $("#sendRoute").live('click', function(){     
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://test.whirlware.biz/server/",
  type: "POST",
  data: { 
    route : trackCoords_str,
    timeInMinutes: final_time_m_str,
    timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded_str,
    averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str,
    distance: total_km_rounded_str,
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(){ 
    alert('success!');
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.responseText); alert(thrownError); }
 });
});
```

Comment: почему у вас javascript относится к серверному коду? у вас в ответе должен быть json, а не кусок javascript-a

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно в итоге вывести javascript код, php нужен только для получения и обработки переменных, а я не знаю как правильно "смешать" их вместе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

Вы говорите jQuery, что данные обязательно придут в формате json:

```
dataType: "json"
```

JSON может выглядеть так:

```
{"total_km_rounded":12,"final_time_m":72,"final_time_s_rounded":4345,"aver_speed_km_h_rounded":10}
```

В общем-то, вы так описываете объект data при его передаче на сервер ajax-запросом.

Вывод же начинается так:

```
 
 
<script>
var total_km_rounded = ...
```

(я специально отметил пустые переносы строк - в JSON'e вообще-то на это наплевать, но с xml такое могло и не пройти, да и вообще, зачем использовать компактную передачу данных, если вы ее банально размазываете?)

Ошибка "Unexpected token <" вылезает на теге "script", потому что он никоим образом к JSON не относится. JSON может начинаться с символов "{" и "[" (иногда - кавычки и цифры), и больше ничего, потому что он описывает исключительно объекты/массивы, а не выполняемый код, как у вас. Даже если вы получите данные в таком виде, то вам придет одна большая строка, которую еще надо будет запульнуть в документ, чтобы она начала работать.

И еще:

```
$trackCoords1 = json_decode($route, false);
$final_time_m1 = json_decode($timeInMinutes, false);
$final_time_s_rounded1 = json_decode($timeInSeconds, false);
$aver_speed_km_h_rounded1 = json_decode($averageSpeed, false);
$total_km_rounded1 = json_decode($distance, false);
```

Данные на сервере приходят НЕ в JSON'е, в $***_***POST у вас уже содержатся готовые значения. JSON - это всегда одна большая строка (а у вас их тут пять, что уже должно породить сомнения), если JSON'ом передаются конкретные значения (что, на самом деле, не JSON уже), то они выглядят ровно так же, как их строковая репрезентация, т.е. json***_***decode здесь может быть нужен только для того, чтобы перегнать цифры из строкового типа в числовые типы (и для этого есть функции попроще, не говоря уж о том, что PHP вообще не заботится о том, в строках у него числа или в нормальных типах). json***_***decode здесь вообще не нужен, потому что (еще раз) - JSON это не какая-то там яваскриптовая магия, а просто компактный способ записать данные в одну строку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ситуация такая: мне нужно просто отправить JSON с клиента и получить на сервере а затем вывести в javascript т.к дальше с ним будут проводится манипуляции. Как это можно сделать? Может быть без JSON, а есть другой метод?

Comment: Смотря что вам надо отдавать, если JSON, то нет, если скрипт, то он не должен запрашиваться через ajax. Обычно при асинхронном опросе скрипт сам выполняет какие-то действия, основываясь на переданных данных, кроме данных не передается ничего.

Comment: Нужно отдать данные: скорость, время, расстояние и т.п всё в числовом формате, получить эти данные на сервере и вывести на экран. Я думаю JSON формат для этого подходит лучше всего. Задача вроде простая но уже и так кучу ошибок поисправлял, теперь здесь затык. Пробовал убирать строки с json_decode и выводить данные но все равно ошибка, главная цель: получить на сервере данные которые записываются из переменных на клиенте в json, как их получить это уже не особо важно, главно чтобы они корректно отобразились

Comment: Они в любом случае придут в $_POST или в $_GET (в зависимости от того, как передается), надо забрать их оттуда, произвести необходимые манипуляции и отдать json-объект в вышеприведенном формате (проще всего собрать в PHP ассоциативный массив и преобразовать его с помощью json_encode). После получения данных скриптом отобразить их, т.е. в success:function(){} запихнуть всю логику по отображению.

Comment: Спасибо. С этим уже решил сейчас другая проблема.